# Persistent Image Loading Spinner Overlay on Product Images in Custom WordPress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, image-loading, custom-theme

I'm currently managing a WordPress-based ecommerce site with a custom theme. When navigating to any product page, the product images are perpetually overlaid with a loading spinner and a white background, effectively rendering the images invisible. This issue is present despite the images being loaded properly, as confirmed by inspecting the element and viewing the image URL directly. The problem disappears when I switch to another theme, indicating the issue lies within the custom theme. The error console does not report any issues.

I've tried inspecting the CSS and identified that the issue might be tied to the '#app[v-cloak]::after' and '#app::after' pseudo-elements in the init.css file. I've attempted to comment out the CSS rules relating to these pseudo-elements, expecting the loading spinner and white overlay to disappear, but the issue persists. I've confirmed that these changes have been saved and are active, and I've also tried clearing the cache, and also desactivated all plugins to reactivate them one by one to see if there is any conflicts but no. I suspect there might be some JavaScript code causing this, but I'm unsure how to confirm and resolve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.